# Ubuntu Server 16.04 LTS internet not working at all

Tags: networking, 16.04, server

I am running Ubuntu Server 16.04 LTS. anything network related doesn't seem to work. sudo apt-get update says temporary failure to resolve host. curl and ping both just hang when I run them. there is no output at all. I think this started happening when I got a new router.

EDIT:
`ping -c4 8.8.4.4`

```
PING 8.8.4.4 (8.8.4.4) 56(84) bytes of data.

--- 8.8.4.4 ping statistics ---
4 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 3023ms
```

`ifconfig`
Returns

```
enp2s8    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:0c:f1:b3:b6:b0
          inet addr:192.168.2.208  Bcast:192.168.2.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::20c:f1ff:feb3:b6b0/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:478724 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:225770 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:54169875 (54.1 MB)  TX bytes:17520767 (17.5 MB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:203 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:203 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1
          RX bytes:15524 (15.5 KB)  TX bytes:15524 (15.5 KB)

tun0      Link encap:UNSPEC  HWaddr 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00
          inet addr:10.8.0.1  P-t-P:10.8.0.2  Mask:255.255.255.255
          UP POINTOPOINT RUNNING NOARP MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:100
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
```

`sudo cat /etc/network/interfaces`
Returns

```
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).

source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
auto enp2s8
iface enp2s8 inet dhcp
```

The computer is connected with an ethernet cable, and I am running ubuntu server as said in the title meaning I don't have a GUI.

`sudo dhclient enp2s8`
Returns nothing.

I hope this helps!

Comment: How about `ping -c4 8.8.4.4`?

Comment: can you post the output of `ifconfig` and `sudo cat /etc/network/interfaces` ?

Comment: Could you please [edit] your question to include the output of the terminal command `LC_MESSAGES=POSIX nm-tool`? Thanks.

Comment: `dhclient`, not `dfclient`

Comment: @DavidFoerster it says command not found?

Comment: Alright, that's already a hint because it means you're not using "network manager".

Answer (score -1):

Connect the pc to the router on an ethernet cable. This eliminates the wireless layer as a source of trouble.

Use that to find out if your router works at all. If it is not getting to the outside world, you will see the trouble like you describe--nothing works.

If ethernet is working on the wire, then problem is wireless driver configuration.

You don't mention which desktop you are using, but most have the Network Manager applet.  That has some GUI configuration.

Also, if you want to understand better what is going wrong, the most general advice is to open a terminal and run "dmesg" to summarize all the system level errors.

Comment: The question itself lacks much needed information so sadly your answer is shooting from the hip.  1. He very well may be using a patch cable. 2. Plugging directly into the router will not get him any further if the interface is configured incorrectly. 3. Once again, we don't know if he is trying to use a wireless adapter. 4. He most likely isn't using any gui (he said he's using Server 16.04) which he would have had to go out of his way to install.  More information is needed.